# Unexpected token in JSON at position 43

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json

Im trying to Fetch Data From a PHP Server Running MySQL. In my angular controller I do `$http.get("dbconnection.php")`

In my dbconnection.php I have this code which just Selects everything from the database and sends it back.

```
$conn = new mysqli......

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM ...");

$outp = "";

while ($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {
        $outp .= ",";
    }
    $outp .= '{"id":"' . $rs["id"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"name":"' . $rs["name"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"price":"' . $rs["price"] . '"}';
    $outp .= '"created":"' . $rs["created"] . '"}';
    $outp .= '"img":"' . $rs["img"] . '"}';
}
$outp = '{"records":[' . $outp . ']}';
$conn->close();

echo $outp;
```

When I visit my site to see take a look at the Data under

`Network Tab > XHR > dbconnection.php > Preview`

I see the data but its weird formatted.

[See picture of weird formatted json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndVYU.png)

I think thats the reason for why I get the

`Unexpected token in JSON at position 43` ERROR
when I am trying to fetch the data.

Comment: There is `json_encode` function. Do __not__ invent the wheel.

Comment: The last characters in the lines where `price` and `created` are added are `}` instead of `,`

Comment: @ChrisForrence Thanks! That was wrong also. But didn't fix the problem :)

Comment: by the way try to validate your json using [jsonlint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) to check where is exactly the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To got well formatted JSON outputs, use `json_encode` function.

In your case :

```
$conn = new mysqli......

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM ...");
$json = ["records" => []];

while ($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $json["records"][] = $rs;
}
$conn->close();

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Okay it's working now. Thank you dude. You made my day!